# How do we handle duplicate questions and promote the idea of 'search before asking'

Tags: discussion, questions

I came across this question:

*"What additional benefits does an QA /Developer engineer bring to a project"*

... and the first thing it reminded me of is a similar question being asked in recent past:

*"What benefit does having developer experience or background have on the effectiveness of a tester?"*

As the community grows, the duplication of questions will increase.

How do we promote and encourage users to search before asking a questions?

How do we deal with the duplicate threads?  Maybe, provide the link to the previously asked (and answered) question and close the duplicate question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At 250 rep, you get an option to close a question.

```
250     Vote to close, reopen, or migrate your questions
```

One of the reasons for closing is exact duplicate, at which point you're prompted for a link to the duplicated question.

There's a post on the main meta (that doesn't sound right...) that covers a lot of the standard questions about duplicates. Check it out [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-to-handle-duplicate-questions)!